# ¿Cómo obtener la ubicación actual del teléfono en Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy trabajando con Google Maps y necesito mostrar la ubicación del usuario en el mapa, para hacer esto uso un plugin llamado GeolocatorPlugin de James Montemagno.

El problema es que en el deploy de la aplicación se cae, creo que el problema se produce porque estoy llamando un método asíncrono desde mi contentpage, por lo tanto al pedirme la autorización para usar la ubicación antes de presionar permitir se cae la aplicación completa. Luego que la aplicación ya está en el teléfono al iniciarla no se cae, esto solo pasa en el deploy de la aplicación.

La pregunta en definitiva es: ¿desde dónde puedo llamar este método para que se ejecute asíncronamente? (aquí está mi código):

```
namespace CustomRenderer
{
    public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            findMeAsync();
        }

        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task findMeAsync()
        {            
            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout,includeHeading: false); 
        } 
    }      
}
```

Comment: como te fue con la respues no marcaste y no publicate tu solucion

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el método `OnApearing` Algo así:

```
 protected override  async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        /*Como puedes ver aquí, podemos esperar metodos Async*/
        await DisplayAlert("Prueba", "Este metodo es esperable", "ok");

    }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda !